# Jmeter.bat does not properly handle arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, jmeter, headless

I know this worked once, but now it fails.

In JMeter 4, on Windows 10, when I try to run %JMETER_HOME%\bin\jmeter.bat with arguments, as such:

```
C:\>jmeter.bat -n -t EcomProductSearch.jmx -Dtest.environment=uat -Dtest.duration=3600 -Dload.multiplier=36
```

Instead of loading headless and running with arguments, instead I get the GUI load, and then this error:

[image]

It's taking the entire line after the batch file name, and pulling the whole line in as an argument to -t. It's not doing what the docs say it should.

Comment: are you sure `EcomProductSearch.jmx` is in c:\ directory?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`-J`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#using_variables) for properties:

```
-Jtest.environment=uat -Jtest.duration=3600 -Jload.multiplier=36
```

> You can then change some or all of the values on the command-line as follows:
>
> ```
>  jmeter … -Jhost=www3.example.org -Jloops=13
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue therefore my expectation is that your JMeter installation got broken somehow:

[image]

Try downloading the original version of [jmeter.bat](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/bin/jmeter.bat) file and compare it with the one you have, most probably there are inconsistencies.

Also be aware that according to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#best_practices) [you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider downloading [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1/) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page). The most recent JMeter versions have performance improvements and bug fixes so it might be the case you're suffering from issue which has the fix already.